# Adding EventRecevier in SandBox Sharepoint2010

Tags: sharepoint-online, event-receivers, sandbox-solution

This is Sample of my Code

SPList list = new SPSite(siteURL).OpenWeb().Lists[listName];
SPEventReceiverDefinitionCollection eventReceivers = list.EventReceivers;

SPEventReceiverDefinition eventReceiver = eventReceivers.Add();

but when i use this code it returns error while Build Project and error is

```
Error 1 'Microsoft.SharePoint.SPEventReceiverDefinitionCollection' does not contain a definition for 'Add' and no extension method 'Add' accepting a first argument of type 'Microsoft.SharePoint.SPEventReceiverDefinitionCollection' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

The Error is in line eventReceivers.Add();
What Should I do now? can anybody help me Its Urgent.. Its a Sandboxed Solution..

Answer (score 0):

If you have no restrictions then change scope of your project from Sandboxed to Farm. It will work. I have the same Problem and I got the solution after I changed the Scope.

Comment: If you found this answer helpful then don't forget to mark as answer. So that if someone else get this problem can get the solution.

Comment: I cant change the scope from sandbox to farm . as i want this solution to work with office 365. And office 365 only need Sandbox solutions.   ;(